# Schtasks Permissions Error on Administrative User?

Tags: batch-file, cortana, windows-task-scheduler

I am extremely noobish when it comes to this as I literally just started doing it, but today I just decided I was going to explore a bit, I was going to try to make a simple batch file so I could make Cortana run it to close certain tasks, by just saying "Run ," so I tried this, and I have so far

`SCHtasks /end /s Titan /u vetri /tn chrome`

I get a prompt to enter my password, and I do and I get returned back:

`ERROR: User credentials are not allowed on the local machine.`

Comment: Are you administrator on the system `Titan`? If you are just running this on your local machine you may want to remove the `/s Titan` and try again